# Grails - stop or reschedule a job

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

I am dynamically scheduling jobs, at this way:

`JobClass.schedule(Long interval, Integer repeatCount, Map params )`

Later I want to stop the job from running, and then restart them again according to the users actions.

How could I stop this trigger?

The only way that did actually stop it was `JobClass.removeJob()`, but I wasn;t able to start it again later, so I need something else.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use Scheduler class having methods unscheduleJob which just delete all the triggers bind with the job. For scheduler class object:

Inject in service

```
def jobManagerService
```

use the code to unschedule the job

```
jobManagerService.getQuartzScheduler().unscheduleJob(TriggerKey triggerkey)
```

to start the job scheduling: just create a new trigger for the same job and schedule it.

```
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                .withIdentity(triggerName, triggerGroupName)
                .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
                .withIntervalInSeconds())
                .forJob(JobKey.jobKey(jobName, groupName))
                .build()

        jobManagerService.getQuartzScheduler().scheduleJob(trigger);
```

Comment: I schduled the job like this:
Trigger trigger = new CronTrigger(...) or 
                = new SimpleTrigger(...)    
trigger.setJobName("")
trigger.setJobGroup("GRAILS_JOBS")
jobManagerService.getQuartzScheduler().scheduleJob(trigger)