# After Starting Cron Job from Controller how can i stop it from controller

Tags: grails, groovy, quartz-scheduler

I start a cron job from a controller with this code. Please help me with a solution for how I can stop the cron Job from controller.

//Controller

```
 def StartJob(){    
            def quartzScheduler
            def cronExpression = "*/10 * * * * ?"
                 MyJob.schedule(cronExpression, [id:"111"])
        }
```

//Cron Job

```
class MyJob {

    static triggers = {}

    def execute(context) {
        println context.mergedJobDataMap.get('id')

    }
```

I an using ':quartz:1.0.2' plugin and grails 3.6.2

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grails - stop or reschedule a job](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370429/grails-stop-or-reschedule-a-job)

Comment: How can i set .withIdentity("myJob", "group1")